# TypeScript Type 'Promise<void | Object>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<Object>' on Promise.then()

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

I am currently trying to implement a service for caching document in base64 format. I want this service to fetch a document from sessionStorage, and if there is no document in sessionStorage, fetch it from IRequestService and then save it to sessionStorage. I tried this approach, but I am getting a type error

```
Type 'Promise<void | GetDocumentResult>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<GetDocumentResult>'.
```

The code looks like this:

```
getDocument(requestId: string, documentId: DocumentID, requestService: IRequestService): Promise<GetDocumentResult> {
    if (this.storageKey in sessionStorage) {
      const documentsMap: Map<DocumentID, GetDocumentResult> = new Map(JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(this.storageKey)!))
      if (documentsMap.get(documentId) !== undefined) {
        return new Promise(resolve => resolve(documentsMap.get(documentId)!))
      }
    }

    return requestService.getDocument(requestId, documentId)
      .then(value => {this.setDocument(documentId, value)})
}
```

I was expecting return type of Promise< GetDocumentResult >.then to be Promise< GetDocumentResult >, but for some reason which I dont understand, it's Promise<void | GetDocumentResult>

Do someone knows why this is happening?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already explained, your `then` callback does return `void` not the result. You're looking for

```
getDocument(requestId: string, documentId: DocumentID, requestService: IRequestService): Promise<GetDocumentResult> {
  if (this.storageKey in sessionStorage) {
    const documentsMap: Map<DocumentID, GetDocumentResult> = new Map(JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(this.storageKey)!));
    const document = documentsMap.get(documentId);
    if (document !== undefined) {
      return Promise.resolve(document);
    }
  }

  return requestService.getDocument(requestId, documentId).then(value => {
    this.setDocument(documentId, value);
    return value;
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  });
}
```

Btw, I would recommend to extract the cache lookup and storage (`setDocument`?) into a separate service, and to have that service keep the `documentsMap` in memory instead of parsing JSON every time `getDocument` is called.

Comment: Hello, thank you kind sir. You are indeed right. Have a nice day.

Comment: I am not sure how to achieve what you are suggesting. The code I posted is part of DocumentSessionStorageService, an implementation of IDocumentStorageService. What do you mean by extracting the cache lookup? Don't I need to parse a json every time I want to check whether the document is cached?

Comment: Why not do `this._documentsMap = new Map(JSON.parse(sessionStorage[this.storageKey]))` just once in the constructor of your `DocumentSessionStorageService`?

Comment: Dumb me. Thank you again sir

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you have  an issue because you are not returning anything inside your **.then()**

here:

```
 .then(value => {this.setDocument(documentId, value)})
```

and that makes your returned type be `Promise<void>` instead of `Promise<GetDocumentResult>`

final versions should be like here:

```
getDocument(requestId: string, documentId: DocumentID, requestService: IRequestService): Promise<GetDocumentResult> {
    if (this.storageKey in sessionStorage) {
      const documentsMap: Map<DocumentID, GetDocumentResult> = new Map(JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(this.storageKey)!))
      if (documentsMap.get(documentId) !== undefined) {
        return new Promise(resolve => resolve(documentsMap.get(documentId)!))
      }
    }

    return requestService.getDocument(requestId, documentId)
      .then(value => { return this.setDocument(documentId, value)})
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for reply. I already tried this, but as I understand promises, there is nothing to be returned in .then method since it's just a success callback. When I add return, nothing changes. Type of .then first parameter is (value: GetDocumentResult) => void | PromiseLike< void >

Comment: Your answer was partialy right, but return type of setDocument is void, I have to return value. And my comment is incorrect, I should return a value in .then. Have a nice day

Comment: @omastik glad it helped, no problem :)